# Why isn't the cofinality of $\lambda^\kappa$ equal to $\kappa$, in contradiction to König's theorem?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I came across the definition of cofinality and there is something I don't understand : König's theorem tells us that $\operatorname{cof}(\lambda^\kappa)>\kappa$ but since $\lambda^\kappa:=\bigcup\limits_{\gamma<\kappa}\lambda^{\gamma}$, the map
\begin{align}
\kappa &\to \lambda^{\kappa}\\
\gamma &\mapsto \lambda^{\gamma}
\end{align}
should be cofinal no? So $\operatorname{Cof}(\lambda^{\kappa})\le \kappa$ no? What did I get wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda^\kappa:=\bigcup\limits_{\gamma<\kappa}\lambda^{\gamma}$ holds for ordinals (if $\kappa$ is a limit, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation) e.g.), but the statement for the cofinality is a statement about cardinals.

You would not say that $\bigcup_{n < \aleph_0} \aleph_0^n = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ would you?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. So if $\lambda^{\kappa}$ is the ordinal exponentiation, then $\operatorname{\lambda^{\kappa}}\le\kappa$ would be correct, but if $\lambda^\kappa$ is the cardinal exponention, then it would be wrong, is that it?

Comment: @roi_saumon You give (In cardinal terms) the definition of $\lambda^{<\kappa}$ not $\lambda^\kappa$. But it also corresponds to [ordinal exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation) as well.

Comment: Okay. But is my comment right or wrong? $\bigcup_{n < \omega_0} \omega_0^n = \omega_0^{\omega_0}$?

Comment: @roi_saumon that’s wrong, as a countable union of countable sets is countable and the power of $\aleph_0$ by itself is continuum and hence uncountable.

Comment: But $\bigcup_{n < \omega_0} \omega_0^n$ is the ordinal exponention of $\omega_0$ by $\omega_0$?

Comment: @roi_saumon yes, that’s the union of $\omega$ copies of $\omega$ so again $\omega$.

Comment: So $\omega_0^{\omega_0}$ doesn't denote the ordinal exponentiation of $\omega_0$ by $\omega_0$? That is very confusing

Comment: @roi_saumon if I use $\omega$ I mean the ordinal and by $\aleph_0$ I mean the same set as a cardinal. The operations (also multiplication and addition) mean different things for ordinals and cardinals.

Comment: Yes, this is why in my first comment I ask the question if $\bigcup_{n < \omega_0} \omega_0^n = \omega_0^{\omega_0}$ and not $\bigcup_{n < \aleph_0} \aleph_0^n = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$. So is the answer still the same?

Comment: @roi_saumon as ordinals $\bigcup_{n < \omega} \omega^n = \omega^\omega = \omega$ but as **cardinals** (which is what König's theorem is about), $\bigcup_{n < \aleph_0} \aleph_0^n = \aleph_0 < \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @Henno: $\omega^\omega\neq\omega$, as ordinals. What is true is that $2^\omega=\omega$ as ordinal exponentiation goes.

Comment: Okay. To make sure I understood properly. $card(\aleph_0^2):=card(\aleph_0\times \aleph_0)=card(\aleph_0)$. So $card(\aleph_0^n)=card(\aleph_0)$. Consequently, I have $\bigcup\limits_{n < \aleph_0} \aleph_0^n=\aleph_0\neq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}:=card(\{f: \aleph_0\to\aleph_0\})$. The mistake I made is actually thinking that in Königs result "$\operatorname{cof}(\alpha^{\kappa})>\kappa$", the exponention was the ordinal exponention (because it actually is the cardinal exponention). What do you think?

Comment: @roi_saumon yes, that’s right. You need the right exponentiation. It’s the only nontrivial operation of cardinal arithmetic and König is one of the few things we know in ZFC.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanations

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, by the way what you really meant is $\operatorname{cof}(\omega^{\omega})=\omega$ right?

Comment: @roi_saumon it has the advantage of being true at least.

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely not true that $\lambda^\kappa=\bigcup_{\gamma<\kappa}\lambda^\gamma$. Just take $\kappa=\omega$ to understand how wrong that may be.

What you describe is $\lambda^{<\kappa}$, which indeed has a cofinal sequence of length $\kappa$, although it might very well be that $\lambda^\gamma$ is *constant*. Cardinal exponentiation is kinda tricky this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped